# Eclipse (3.4): how to get Problems to appear automatically if one has errors?

Tags: eclipse, flexbuilder

When I build my projects in FlexBuilder, I want to see any errors immediately; I don't want to have to hover or open the Problem pane every time, nor do I want to always leave it open.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is a problem.

As far as I know the Eclipse settings and there is no such.

You can use shortcut keys SHIFT+ALT+Q and press X to fast open the problem panel.